# Multiple sites with 1 kohana core on same server

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, widget, hmvc

I think it has to be possible, but didn't find anything useful yet...

Is it possible to run multiple websites with from 1 Kohana core? Basically all website's are the same, only the layout is different. (Just a different view-folder, (works)) and the content is a bit different. (This is based on constant SITE_ID that pulls it from the db, (also works))

The only two things are, how do I configure this in my bootstrap/index.php? I thought of checking the url. With that url perform a query on the table 'websites' (select where url = '$url') and get the right SITE_ID and view from that query. 
In that way both x.com y.com and z.com will pull up the same index.php file. After that SITE_ID is defined and with that id the right content is loaded and the right view is used.

Also, how can I do this in combination with widgets. I have like 8 different widgets and each website displays 3 of those 8 over different pages. So x.com/a will display widget 'widget_1' and 'widget_2', x.com/b will display 'widget_2' and 'widget_3'. But y.com/a has to display 'widget_6' and 'widget_7' and y.com/b has to display 'widget_3' and 'widget_4'.
Is there a way this can be managed? I didn't worked a lot with widgets before and now I want to use it in combination with multiple sites...

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple sites handled via database within a single instance; what you're doing is similar to a multisite CMS. I have experience developing CMSes, both of the single site and multisite sort; I can tell you through experience that developing a multisite CMS is significantly more complex than doing multiple instances of single CMS. I usually opt for the latter if having multisite is not a requirement from the client and the implementation is up to me.

Have you considered multiple instances of websites with separate folders?

For multiple instances of single sites, I suggest reading http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/sharing-kohana to get a better idea of how do go about having multiple sites with single (or even multiple core).